# How can I get rid of my "@types/react/index" can only be default-imported using 'esModuleInterp' flag lint in React/TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint

It's as simple as stated above: React 16.9.22 with TypeScript 3.8.2.  It doesn't affect anything, just crowds my warning window form actually useful things.

In my tsconfig I have:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {    
    "esModuleInterop": true
  }
}
```

But every file have the line `import React from 'react';`

I get the linting error:

> .../node_modules/@types/react/index"' can only be default-imported
>   using the 'esModuleInterop' flag

possibly relevant deps:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^2.22.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^2.22.0",
    "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
    "eslint": "^6.6.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^4.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^2.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.18.3",
    "typescript": "^3.8.2"
  },
```

Comment: Did you try the suggestion found in https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/33097 to change to `import * as React from 'react'`?

Comment: you are the best!

Comment: For those who are still encountering this: Make sure you have `**/*.tsx` files in your includes list. I had only included `**/*.ts` which caused the above mentioned error.

Comment: [Restarting the IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62273153/this-module-is-declared-with-using-export-and-can-only-be-used-with-a-defau/62275620#62275620) or already `F1 → TypeScript: Reload Project` in VSCode helped in my case

Answer (score 23):

What worked for me was adding the following in my tsconfig.json file in the compilerOptions:

```
"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
"esModuleInterop": true
```

Comment: This worked for me in StackBlitz!

Comment: Why do I need both and not just the first `allowSynt..`

Answer (score 6):

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";
```

This is the most futureproof way to import React. If you set `--allowSyntheticDefaultImports` (or add `"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true`) in your `tsconfig.json` you can use more familiar imports:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
```

source: https://github.com/typescript-cheatsheets/react

Answer (score 3):

**Alternatively, we can separate the imports as below for example**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, FC } from 'react';
```

to

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { useState, useEffect, FC } from 'react';
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting this error and already have the following in your `tsconfig.json`:

```
"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
"esModuleInterop": true
```

you might want to restart your vs code.