# This module is declared with using 'export =', and can only be used with a default import when using the 'esModuleInterop' flag

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm trying to make a simple API using `typescript` and `NodeJS` but when I run my code I get this error

> "This module is declared with using 'export =', and can only be used
>   with a default import when using the 'esModuleInterop' flag."

This is my code:
package.json

```
    {
  "name": "API-Proyecto",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/cors": "^2.8.6",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.6",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.4"
  }
}
```

Index.ts

```
    import express from 'express';
import { Request, Response }  from 'express';
import cors from 'cors';

const app = express();

app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.json);
app.use(cors({origin: true, credentials: true}));

app.get('/api/auth/testing', (req: Request, res: Response) =>{
    res.status(200).json({
        ok : true,
        msg : 'hi from my method'
    });
});

app.listen(3000, () => {console.log('Server running on 3000' )});
```

tsconfig.json

```
    {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",                          /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', 'ES2018', 'ES2019', 'ES2020', or 'ESNEXT'. */
    "module": "commonjs",                     /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', 'es2020', or 'ESNext'. */
    "outDir": "./dist",                        /* Redirect output structure to the directory. */
    "esModuleInterop": true,                  /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */
  }
}
```

Comment: Your code is fine. If you are curious on this flag I've created a lesson on it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bx4AjADk6eQ

Comment: Thank you so much! I don't have an idea about the error but your lesson is helpful to learn more

Comment: In my case the 
    "esModuleInterop": true was missing

Comment: I had a similar problem, but I forgot to create de tsconfig.json file. once i generated it, the issue was fixed

Comment: This one is missing [Interop Constraints](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#Interop_Constraints_6252)

Answer (score 185, accepted):

Your code is perfectly fine.

## Fix

When you make changes to tsconfig, sometimes you need to restart your IDE or Code Editor

Comment: If you are using VSCode, you can run `TypeScript: Reload Project` from the command pallet.

Answer (score 114):

Use:

```
import * as express from 'express';
```

Comment: I had a similar issue for momentjs in VSCode and your approach resolved my case.

Comment: This raised a tsserver error on `express()`: `This expression is not callable. Type 'typeof e' has no call signatures. (tsserver 2349)`

Comment: Maybe you're using a version of the `express` package that doesn't return a function by default, so I recommend either looking in the documentation or trying to find it in their project implementation or doing a debug to see everything that is exported by `express`, because there may be some version that needs to call a function inside the object, which would be something like `express.function()`.

Answer (score 34):

My problem was that I tried to run `tsc` as `tsc -w index.ts`.

However, as said here https://stackoverflow.com/a/33244030/5711655 if you run `tsc` with a specified input file, it **won't use** the `tsconfig.json` in your project directory! So in my case I had to use `tsc -w`.

Comment: That is so annoying that tsc ignores tsconfig.json when called with a specific file argument.

Answer (score 22):

I fixed similar mistake for yourself. I use project (vite + vue 3 + ts)

1. added on tsconfig.json->compilerOptions + "moduleResolution": "node".
2. `import  moment from "moment"` to `import * as moment from "moment";`

UPD:-
and add this setting,

```
"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
```

and then I can use,
`import moment from "moment";`

Comment: `import * as somelibrary from "somelibrary"` worked for me thanks.

Answer (score 20):

I was able to solve it by setting the `"esModuleInterop"` property to `true` inside the `"compilerOptions"` object in the tsconfig.json file.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    ...
  },
}
```

Comment: helped in my case as well

Answer (score 7):

Don't forget to set `"moduleResolution": "node"` in the `tsconfig.json` if you are using node.

Answer (score 7):

when working with Ts you you need to add a flag on your tsconfig.json file that allow Synthetic Imports as so:

- open tsconfig.json
- add:
  {
  "compilerOptions": {
  "jsx": "react",
  "module": "es6",
  "target": "es6",
  "moduleResolution": "node",
  "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  }
  }

Hope it helps.
Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem by compiling the whole file instead of compiling individual files.

Just run the following command to compile the whole file in a go

```
npx tsc
```

This should solve your problem

Comment: It works for me with conjunction with this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74788007/7883681

Comment: Any idea why this is?

Answer (score 2):

As with most answers here, I have tested a wide variety of settings in the `tsconfig.json` file and none have resolved my issue.

**Response:** In the end, I needed to change the way I am importing the express module:

**server.ts:**

```
import express = require('express'); //! import express from 'express';
import { Express, Request, Response } from 'express';

const SERVER_PORT: number = 3000;

const app: Express = express();

app.use(express.json());

app.get("/", (request: Request, response: Response) => {
    return response.json({ message: "Hello world!!!" });
});

app.listen(SERVER_PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server running at: http://localhost:${SERVER_PORT}`);
});
```

And **tsconfig.json:**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2020",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "types": ["node", "express"],
    "lib": [
            "ES2020",
            "DOM",
        ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, I found that switching from

```js
import * as blah from 'blah-lib';
```

To

```js
const blah = require('blah-lib');
```

Fixed the issue at compile time.

Comment: this is not a solution since he wants to use esModules style

Answer (score 1):

Just like @basarat said rightfully, restarting Typescript can fix this issue. I already included `"esModuleInterop": true,` in `tsconfig.json`.
I want to add, that you can do this via the Intellij Footer as well. Click on your Typescript version there.

Thanks for the help.

[image: Intellij Footer]

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering a lot but a friend helped me:

1. You need to create a command inside of "scripts" part on package.json

**Package.json**

```
{
  "name": "api-proyecto",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    **"build-dev": "tsc -w"**
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/cors": "^2.8.6",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.6"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1"
  }
}
```

2. To run your script you need to type the following line

   npm i run **build-dev** (because it's the name of our command)
3. Finally in another powershell launch node normally. For Example:

   node .\dist\index.js

Answer (score 0):

After trying all of the above solutions to no avail, I stumbled upon a solution for my case. I don't know why this works but running `tsc` instead of `tsc index.ts` or `tsc --watch index.ts` compiled fine. This error makes no sense to me at all. If someone can enlighten me and other readers of this post, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is already explained in an earlier answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67619647/224639

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything on this thread and it didn't work. What finally did was swapping `tsc` for `ts-node` to compile typescript in the app.

For reference I had this problem in a rushjs monorepo which may have further confused `tsc`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with my vscode, the error keeps on popping even with changing the `tsconfig.json`.

The problem was that `tsconfig.json` was extending from `expo/tsconfig.base` and somehow vscode didn't detect it.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "src/*": ["src/*"],
      "static/*": ["static/*"]
    }
  },
  "extends": "expo/tsconfig.base"
}
```

I just opened this `expo/tsconfig.base` with right click and then save it to make vscode aware of this.